# JavaScript ui-autocomplete input doesn't focus

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a problem with using `focus()` on an element which has `ui-autocomplete`

```
<input id="headerSearch" class="header-search-form-input form-control ui-autocomplete-input" name="query" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

and when I use `$('#headerSearch').focus()` to set cursor into a input field it doesn't work.
I've read that it might be because this field already have event on it. I've checked it in Google Chrome EventListener and, yes, it has `event.focus()` on this field.

So my question is. How I can set focus and cursor on this field if it already have event on it?
Thanks for helping.

**UPD**

I've found how to `remove` event from `ui-component`, but `focus()` it still doesn't work.

```
$('#headerSearch').off('focus'); 
$('#headerSearch,.header-search-form-label').focus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I click on a button the `input` will display (before it - hidden), maybe `input` for some time "not displayed" for the browser and it could not get `focus` because of it. So I did like that (it works):

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#headerSearch').focus(); }, 100);
```

Then I saw that I don't have to delete the event `focus` for this `input`. I think because I use `method`, not an `event`. But for some reason, many answers (when I try to find a solution) tell to delete the event if `focus` doesn't work for input.